# LWC refresh data each time a new record is inserted

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, refresh, wire

I have a custom lwc that has a wire call that retrieves a list of records and some required information to be displayed:

```
@AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
public static InterPlanetaryCasesController.IPCasesData getInfo(){
    String query;

    //Method result
    Class.IPCasesData result = new Class.IPCasesData();

    //Fill fieldset and generate query
    query = 'SELECT ';
    for(Schema.FieldSetMember fsm : Class.getInterPlanetaryCasesTableFS()){
        query += fsm.getFieldPath() + ', ';
        
        //Contact Name for datatable proper data display
        if(fsm.getFieldPath().equals('ContactId')){ query += 'Contact.Name, '; }
        
        //Add fieldset member to list
        result.fieldSetLIST.add(new Class.PicklistValue(fsm.getFieldPath(), fsm.getLabel()));
            
    }
    query += 'Id FROM Case WHERE IsClosed = false AND Planet__c != null ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC LIMIT 5';

    //Fill case list
    result.caseLIST = Database.query(query);

    return result;
}

private static List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getInterPlanetaryCasesTableFS() {
    return SObjectType.Case.FieldSets.InterPlanetaryCase.getFields();
}
```

My issue is that I want this lwc to refresh each time a new record is being added or modified. Is this even possible? And if so, how can I achieve this?

Regards,

Comment: Using refreshApex might help, Check this [blog1](http://www.saravanansfdc.com/2020/06/how-to-use-refreshapex-to-refresh-list.html) [blog2](https://www.salesforcepoint.com/2020/08/lwc-refresh-apex-Example.html)

Comment: @AbhinavThakur Hi, thanks for your response! But what I want is to capture from a lwc inserted into a custom tab if a new (for example) Case has been inserted or a existing one has been updated to automatically refresh my data. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [lightning-emp-api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation) to subscribe to a [Change Data Capture](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm) channel, in which your component will then be notified of any creations or updates. In general, you just import the subscribe and unsubscribe methods from lightning-emp-api, subscribe to the object you want to trigger change data capture notifications for, and then handle them in the event handler. Note that there are [limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_allocations.htm) to this feature, so you should be aware of those to see if CDC is suitable for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked perfectly